# Qt Signals and Slots break when converting Visual C++ project to boost build makefile project

Tags: c++, qt4, boost-build

I created a Visual C++ Project using MSVS and I just made another project in MSVS so that the same code can be built using boost build. I can currently build my project using a Visual C++ project as well as a Makefile project that uses boost build.
There is a difference between the two builds though concerning QT Signals and Slots.For the following code,when I call `MyThread::Start()` the `onTimeout()` slot is called when the project is built in visual studio, but not called when built using boost build.

```
class MyThread: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    bool start();
public Q_SLOTS:
    void onTimeout();
private:
    QThread m_thread;
    QTimer m_timer;
};
void MyThread::start()
{
    m_timer.start(1000);
    m_thread.setObjectName(QString("GigeControl"));
    m_thread.start();
    m_timer.moveToThread(&m_thread);
}
void MyThread::onTimeout()
{
    //Do Stuff

}
```

I am really having a hard time trying to figure out the differences between the two 
builds,especially since I need those signals and slots to work.
One major difference that I have noticed so far is that the Visual C++ project is built using `/Zp1` so all structures are 1 byte alligned. This is not done in the boost project as I don't know how to. I've seen people on the internet mentioning that structure allignments (especially using `#pragma pack` can cause problems with QT).

If anyone has some experience they might be able to share it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you running moc with boost build?

Comment: @drescherjm I'm not too familiar with boost build yet but it looks like the Jamfile uses this: `[ cast _ moccable-cpp : [ glob *.cpp ] ]`. I'm not sure if this helps but I just found out that if I build the msvs project and run my boost project then the signals and slots works. This makes me think there is something overlapping with the moc'cing  but I'm not sure how to address it.

Comment: Scratch that, it overwrites the file that I am making so of course it will work :p

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was in fact the structure packing. I am writing code for a couple of code bases that are being merged and there coincidentally happens to be some packing conflicts.
To fix the packing for building with boost-build all I had to to was add this to the lib being generated in the Jamfile:

```
    lib foo
:
    ...
:
    ...
    <target-os>linux:<cxxflags>-fpack-struct=1
    <target-os>windows:<cxxflags>-Zp1
;
```

This worked for me so hopefully it will help someone else out if they get stuck here too